# Arbitrary string assigned to variable?

Tags: macros, strings

How can I assign an arbitrary string - that may include special characters or even macronames - to a variable just as it is? 
e.g. like this: `\newcommand{\mystring}{\assignstring{abc{}\w'\macroname \\}}` wich must results (at least as `\meaning\mystring`): "abc{}\w'\macroname \"

Comment: Wouldn't `\newcommand{\mystring}{abc{}\w'\macroname \\}` do exactly that? Please try and be more precise on what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store an arbitrary string *verbatim* into a *macro* using either `\verbdef` (`verbdef` package) or `\Verbdef` (`newsverb` package).

The difference between both is that the first defines the macro including all font commands required to print the text in the document. The latter only stores the characters, so that they can also be printed to an auxiliary files, which wouldn't be possible with included font commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbdef}
\usepackage{newsverb}

\begin{document}

% In preamble or body
\verbdef\mystringprintable|abc{}\w'\macroname \\|
\Verbdef\mystringplain|abc{}\w'\macroname \\|

% To print:
\mystringprintable
\texttt{\mystringplain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes, "verbatim", that was the world I did not find. Ok, any chance to accept two answers simultaneously? David answers - actually the same solution - was just as useful as Martin's, and they were delivered at the same time. I only accepted Martin's because it gave me a little bit more information. Thanks for both.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you mean (partly because of terminology, Tex doesn't have strings or variables) But I suspect that you want something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbdef}

\verbdef\mystring|{abc{}\w'\macroname \\###|

\begin{document}

\mystring

\end{document}
```